# ng-pattern not working with angular ui datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to use ng-pattern to further enforce the date format on an input field using Angular UI datepicker. The problem is when I do this it's always showing invalid.

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" is-open="opened" close-text="Close"
        ng-model="someDate" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
        ng-pattern="/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/" required />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

If I apply the same ng-pattern to a plain input field (no datepicker), it works as expected.

There seems to be a conflict but I'm not sure what it is. Any ideas?

**Update:**

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9aOFQG6hvL8xwDB8tHKQ) is a simple plunker to illustrate the issue as requested. After some further digging it does seem to be running the pattern against the underlying `Date` object. When I use a custom directive that formats the date, however, it runs it against the actual input.

The only documentation I see for ng-pattern is a brief mention [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) under input. Is there anything else that maybe I'm missing?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe ng-pattern is validating the model value and not the view value.  When you use the datepicker in angular-ui, the model value is saved as a `Date` object, not as a `String`.

Comment: Do you use html2js in your building process? If you do, what version is it?

Comment: @JoseM I thought of that (the documentation is not very clear) but when I replicate on another input backed by a Date object it works, so it seems to be something with the datepicker.

Comment: @JoakimB I'm not familiar with html2js... what does it do?

Comment: @aw04 it minifies html to javascriptfiles and makes them smaller so they load faster. There is a bug in some earlier versions failing ng-pattern. Since you dont use it you wont be affected.

Comment: @JoakimB Ah ok I see the relevance now, thanks

Comment: @aw04 Can you create a [sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f) showing your issue?

Comment: @JoseM Yeah hold on, my work network doesn't seem to trust plunker... I'll set it up when I get home :)

Comment: @aw04 you can also do it on jsfiddle, I just like plunker better

Comment: @JoseM Me too. I've added one, see my update

Comment: @aw04 I looked at the plunker and I also looked at the code for datepicker-popup and I know what is happening.  `datepicker` makes sure the model value is a `Date` object (as long as it can be parsed), but ng-pattern only works on strings.  I was thinking of how to get your requirement to work but more importantly *why* do you need that `ng-pattern` validation?  `datepicker` is already forcing it to be a valid date

Comment: @JoseM My user base isnt the most tech savvy. Many will not use the date picker, and it will convert any integer into a date... if i dont force the correct format it can easily convert to a date not intended. Thanks for all your help, im looking into a way around this as well. Ive got a custom directive to work initially if i set the priority ahead of the datepicker but it fails once the date is changed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, what is happening is that the `datepicker` directive is changing the model value from a `String` to a `Date` object.  When `ngPattern` tried to validate the `Date` object it will fail because the string value of a `Date` is not going to match the pattern that you are using.

What you can do is create your own directive that hooks into the [$parsers of the ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#%24parsers) to run your pattern check and then call `$setValidity()` based on what the value is.  `$parsers` is actually built for this type of functionality where you want to run your own custom validation on a `ngModel` value.

Following these bullets is a directive that will accomplish the functionality that you want. I want to explain the logic in the directive before I show you the code:

- In order to add your own $parser you have to add a require for `ngModel` in your directive definition so that you can access the `ngModelController`
- Because [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) expects the pattern argument without the beginning and trailing slash, I removed them in the pattern directive argument
- `datepicker` changes the model value from a `String` to a `Date`. Since `datepicker` uses `unshift` to add it's $parser function to the beginning of the `$parsers` array, we also need to use `unshift` to put our $parser before `datepicker`'s $parser.
- As you mentioned, the `datepicker` directive will take any value that it can parse into a date and use that for the model.  In order to make sure that only dates which match the pattern are used, I'm returning `undefined` (as specified in the docs) for dates that don't match the pattern.  I'm not doing this check for values that come in as a `Date` object since that means that it was chosen using the `datepicker` widget.
- As I just alluded to in the previous bullet, I'm not doing the validity check if the value is already a `Date` object since that means that it was chosen using the `datepicker` widget and that means that it was a valid date.

**directive code**

```
app.directive('awDatepickerPattern',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs,ngModelCtrl) {
      var dRegex = new RegExp(attrs.awDatepickerPattern);

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {

        if (typeof value === 'string') {
          var isValid = dRegex.test(value);
          ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('date',isValid);
          if (!isValid) {
            return undefined;
          }
        }

        return value;
      });

    }
  };
});
```

**html** - make sure that you don't forget to remove the beginning and trailing slash in the regex definition:

```
aw-datepicker-pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$"
```

And here is an updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VhX5Ac1IJzFCQOXUTYWR) with my code.

### So why again didn't ng-pattern work?

In case you didn't notice the *root* cause for why ng-pattern doesn't work when used with the `datepicker` directive is because the `datepicker` directive adds it's own ngModelController $parser to the **beginning** of the $parsers array by using `unshift`, which changes the model value from a `String` to a `Date`.

Comment: A note to anyone else, I had to set a high priority on this directive to get it to work correctly in my environment

Comment: The same as aw04. Without priority, I always received Date object in the unshift function, so my string parser was never executed.

Comment: Just noticed one issue: if I enter invalid date manually and after that I pick a valid date from datepicker dropdown, then validation still fails. Obviously, picking a valid value does not reset the model state. Maybe this has something to do with changes by Rory G. Anyway, I added a line `ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('datep',true)` at the very beginning of `unshift` to reset the state to valid, and this seems to be working fine now.

Comment: if any test cases are written for this directive, please share it.. it will be helpful..

Answer (score 4):

It seems that an alternative solution to the other workarounds posted here is to upgrade to **AngularJS 1.4.5**, released 2015-08-28:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#145-permanent-internship-2015-08-28

Answer (score 3):

The above directive plunker only works when the date is required. I fixed it by modifying the directive as follows:

```
ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('datep',isValid);
```

Since the date picker runs after this directive it sets 'date' back to valid.

Comment: This probably should have been a comment on the other answer, but I guess new users can't do that.

Comment: Great, thanks. How did you came to the 'datep' value? Is it documented anywhere or did you dig it somewhere in Date Picker's source code?

Comment: It can be anything eg 'datex' as long as it is not 'date'